# knockoutjs function is not invoke when button clicked

Tags: visual-studio-2010, knockout.js

i have one knockout view model function which is not invoke when clicking the button. 
probably i am missing something. i am running the code from VS2010 IDE. i test the same code in jsfiddle and
it is working there but when i try to run the same code from VS2010 IDE then it is not working. any help
would be appreciated. thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #dash
        {
            max-height: 128px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #dash div
        {
            border: 1px solid #de2345;
            padding: 4px;
            margin: 2px;
            line-height: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #dash div:before
        {
            content: '--> ';
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TableModel() 
        {
            var self = this;
            self.Counter = 1;
            self.rows = ko.observableArray([]),
            self.addRow = function () {
                alert('pp');
                self.rows.push(self.Counter + ' ' + new Date());
                self.Counter++;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.rows.shift();
                    self.Counter--;
                }, 3000 + self.rows().length * 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow" type="button">click</button>

    <div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <div data-bind="text:$data">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ko.applyBindings` has to be called when the DOM is loaded. See also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating-knockout).

You can achieve this with:

- put the script block at the bottom of your HTML document, before the closing `body`
- you can leave your script in the `head` secttion and wrap the calling of the ``ko.applyBindings` in a DOM-ready handler such as [jQuery’s ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function

If you are not using jQuery just move your script to the bottom:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow" type="button">click</button>

    <div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <div data-bind="text:$data">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TableModel() 
        {
            var self = this;
            self.Counter = 1;
            self.rows = ko.observableArray([]),
            self.addRow = function () {
                alert('pp');
                self.rows.push(self.Counter + ' ' + new Date());
                self.Counter++;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.rows.shift();
                    self.Counter--;
                }, 3000 + self.rows().length * 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just simply copy paste your code in my aspx form and run it. then i notice nothing visible in page. so please try to run your code at your end first and tell me does it working as expected.

Comment: It was another mistake in your original code: `script` tags cannot be selfclosed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work). So change your first script element to `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>`. I've also updated this is my answer

Comment: well noticed about script tag. it causes the problem. thanks a lot :)